# Get the highest number that is divisible by 4 from a total number ( total = 25, I want 24)

Tags: php

Say I have an array with 25 elements, I want them in four even groups.  So, I want only the first 24 elements.  But if I wind up with 17, I only want 16, etc etc.

I could foreach them, with modulo, checking for the last one that is divisible by 4.  But, it seems like there would be a smarter way? PHP, por favor.

Comment: If you just need the index to use, you could find the modulus of the total (25 % 4 = 1) and subtract it from the total (25 - 1 = 24)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$i -= ($i % 4); //$i is now a multiple of 4
```